# clarifying definition of undecidable

Tags: logic

Because there are examples of both abelian and non abelian groups. Does that mean a group being abelian is undecidable from the group axioms?

And, if so, what contexts and connotations does using the word undecidable introduce? It seems like I only ever see the term in logic and foundations. Why?

Comment: What is true is that the group axioms can't prove that every group is abelian, and they also can't prove that every group is nonabelian (because neither of these statements is true). Calling this "undecidability" is strange. A more interesting question along these lines is whether, given a presentation of a group, you can decide whether it's abelian; I believe the answer is known to be no but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Because there are examples of both abelian and non abelian groups. Does that mean a group being abelian is undecidable from the group axioms?

Yes. Precisely:

- $\varphi$ is *provable from* $T$ if, well, $T\vdash\varphi$; equivalently (by the [Completeness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem)), if every model of $T$ satisfies $\varphi$.
- $\varphi$ is *disprovable from* $T$ if $\neg\varphi$ is provable from $T$.
- $\varphi$ is *unprovable from* $T$ if $\varphi$ isn't provable from $T$, and $\varphi$ is *undecidable from* $T$ if neither $\varphi$ nor $\neg\varphi$ is provable from $T$.

> And, if so, what contexts and connotations does using the word undecidable introduce? It seems like I only ever see the term in logic and foundations. Why?

Undecidability emerges as a property of interest precisely when we're looking at theories that *might be* complete. E.g. it can be surprising to learn that PA isn't complete, that is, that there are sentences in the language of arithmetic which are undecidable from PA. By contrast, there was *never* a thought that the group axioms would be complete, precisely because they emerged to describe a class of *wildly variable* structures (namely, groups). So while you *can* say that commutativity is undecidable in the theory of groups, it sounds a bit off.

Another important point is that the attention given to a *theory as a syntactic object*, rather than just the class of objects it corresponds to, is a key piece of logic: most of the time in group theory, one doesn't really ever need to use the *theory of* groups, we just reason about groups. So the theory of groups itself isn't really an object that crops up frequently and explicitly unless logic is on the mind somewhere.$^*$

---

$^*$Counterexamples welcome!

Comment: I think a good distinction to keep in mind in this situation is the distinction between two purposes for setting up axiomatic systems: (1) to systematize knowledge about a lot of examples by isolating their common properties (e.g. group theory). (2) to describe basic properties of **one** structure as a basis for deducing further information about that structure  (e.g. Euclid's geometry, PA). Incompleteness is interesting in (2) but expected and therefore uninteresting in (1).

Comment: There seems to be another key difference, which I don't quite understand. With groups, it is easy to construct commutative and non-commutative examples, hence commutativity must be undecidable. With arithmetic, it seems hopeless to try to construct a pair of models in which any undecidable statement holds true in one, false in the other. Why is this?

Comment: @WillG $\mathsf{PA}$ is vastly more complicated than the set of group axioms. For example, $\mathsf{PA}$ is not finitely axiomatizable and any axiomatization of $\mathsf{PA}$ requires sentences of arbitrarily large quantifier complexity. Moreover, since $\mathsf{PA}$ suffices to develop a basic theory of computation, models of $\mathsf{PA}$ are "computationally powerful" - in particular, we have Tennenbaum's theorem ruling out any simple nonstandard model. Basically, with groups we're spoiled by simplicity.